# Le sot-l'y-laisse

Tags: étymologie, noms, alimentation

Je connais un restaurant qui s'appelle le **[sot-l'y-laisse](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sot-l%27y-laisse)**, la première fois que je l'ai vu je me suis demandé ce que ça pouvait bien vouloir dire. Après quelques recherches, il semble qu'il s'agisse d'une pièce de volaille.

[image: sot-l'y-laisse] (dessin de [Rainer Zenz](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benutzer:Rainer_Zenz))

J'aimerais savoir d’où vient le nom de cette pièce, cela semble assez inhabituel pour un morceau de volaille ! Les tentatives d'explications que j'ai pu trouver en cherchant sont assez peu convaincantes.

Comment: Maintenant, je me rends compte que tu as visiblement extrait l'image de wikipedia, peut-être peux-tu préciser ce qui ne te satisfait pas dans les explications ?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Je trouve l'article peu satisfaisant : il critique des théories, et avance la sienne, mais sans donner des preuves convaincantes (les citations m'ont l'air soigneusement choisies parmi des sources contradictoires).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wikipedia donne plusieurs liens dans l'article sur [sot-l'y-laisse](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sot-l%27y-laisse) qui tentent expliquer l'origine réelle du nom, et le véritable morceau de volaille qu'il désigne.

La seule chose qui paraît plutôt évidente, et qui n'est pas contestée, est que ce nom signifie : « seul un sot laisserait ce morceau sans le manger ». (Le sot l'y laisse.)

Answer (score 8):

Je suis étonnée que cet article du Figaro sur lequel s'aligne Wikipedia ne fasse aucune référence à Alain Rey à qui j'ai tendance à faire confiance.
Le *Dictionnaire Culturel en Langue Française* (sld Alain Rey) attribue au mot une origine canadienne et le mot aurait d'abord été appliqué à une partie du cerf.

> SOT-L'Y-LAISSE [solilɛs] n.m. invar. (1798n *solilesses* mil. XVIII s.
>   en français du Canada ; de *(le) sot l'y laisse*, d'abord *fol l'y
>   laisse* « chair entre la poitrine et les épaules du cerf » en vénerie
>   à la fin du XIV s.)
>
> Morceau à la chair très fine, de chaque côté de la carcasse d'une
>   volaille (assez peu apparent pour que le « sot l'y laisse » par
>   ignorance) - Le mot s'applique parfois, erronément au croupion.

Answer (score -1):

Morceau très fin du poulet situé à proximité du croupion qui, de ce fait, était plus ou moins oublié. Un jour un gourmet fit allusion à ces deux parties du poulet heureux que personne ne les déguste et il dit à ce moment-là seul le *sot l'y laisse.*

Comment: Malheureusement, ceci n'est pas une explication [étymologique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tymologie).